# Integrating Grammar/Spellcheck Tool in ASP.NET Application for Textarea

Tags: grammar, spell-checking, uitextchecker, grammarly

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET MVC application and aiming to enhance the user experience by integrating a grammar or spellcheck tool into a textarea. I noticed that Grammarly, as well as QuillBot, doesn't seem to offer a direct API that allows me to send text and receive responses which would represent possible text enhancements. The objective is to send user-entered text to the tool's API and display real-time suggestions for corrections on the frontend.

Can anyone recommend a specific tool that meets these criteria?